# HereMap TypeScript : some property lost in @here/maps-api-for-javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, here-api, heremaps

I developed a website with HereMap in react,
use the latest version (2021-11-05T16:33:00+08:00 version:1.30.4) of @here/maps-api-for-javascript,

when develop a draggable Marker/DomMarker component just like official example,

1.I found there were not `draggable` property in marker/domarker in @here/maps-api-for-javascript
2.there were not `target` property in H.util.Event class, It made us hard to get the Object

can HERE Developer Support help us?

**Update 2021-12-16**

Glad to see you

As mentioned previously

Our team see the marker draggable example on Here Official Website

[This is an draggable marker in official web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNYww.png)

[This is Our React Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eDDP.png)

Comment: Could you please add the example reference that you are using as a reference to develop the draggable marker

Comment: glad to see you @HEREDeveloperSupport , I add additional info on the post